# How to use multiple Char Arrays and Float Arrays in a For Loop?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, floating-point

After the first loop, the iteration ignores the "Name of employee #: " and jumps to "Employee's hourly rate: " and "Hours worked: " for the rest of the loop until it finishes. The problem started after I added the "Float" arrays in the "For Loop".

This is the output I am getting:

Name of Employee 1: Alex
Employee's hourly rate: 9.00
Hours Worked: 8

Name of employee 2: Employee's hourly rate:9.50
Hours worked: 8

Name of employee 3: Employee's hourly rate:10.00
Hours worked: 8

etc...

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {   int i;
        char empNames[5][32];
        float empRates[5][10];
        float empHours[5][10];

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            printf("Name of employee %d: ", i+1);
            gets(empNames[i]);

            printf("Employee's hourly rate: ");
            scanf_s("%f", &empRates);//squiggly green line

            printf("Hours Worked: ");
            scanf_s("%f", &empHours);//squiggly green line
        }
      }
```

Errors:
- Warning C4477  'scanf_s' : format string '%f' requires an argument of type 'float *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'float (*)[5][10]'.

-Warning C6272  Non-float passed as argument '2' when float is required in call to 'scanf_s' Actual type: 'float [5][10]'.

-Warning C4013   'gets' undefined; assuming extern returning int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First : gets is dangerous to use you can use fgets instead check this for more informations :[Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Second : empRate[5][10] is a 2D array (Matrix) and you need only a one dimensional array to save your floats each float can fit inside empRate[i](same for empHours)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{  
int i;
char empNames[5][32];
float empRates[5];
float empHours[5];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("Name of employee %d: ", i+1);
    scanf("%32[^\n]s",empNames[i]);
    printf("Employee's hourly rate: ");
    scanf("%f", &empRates[i]);

    printf("Hours Worked: ");
    scanf("%f", &empHours[i]);
    fgetc(stdin); // clear the buffer from the new line character
    }
 }
```

Comment: @spinkoo- Thank you for the help! as for the first line I switched to "scanf_s" instead and it fixed the issue/bugs.  printf("Name of employee: ");
  scanf_s(" %s", &empNames[i], 32);